# cancel the promise call in angular 4

Tags: angular, promise

Is it possible to cancel the promise call in Angular?
I have common service in the following way:

> **commonServices.ts**

```
private getHttpRequest(url: string, requestMethod: RequestMethod, body?: any) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      requestOptionArgs = {
        method: requestMethod
      }
      this.htp.enableSSLPinning(true);
      this.htp.setHeader('*', 'Accept', 'application/json');
        //post request
        if (requestOptionArgs.method == 1) {
            this.paramsPostObj = JSON.parse(body);
            this.htp.setDataSerializer('json');
            this.htp.post(url, this.paramsPostObj, {})
            .then(
            (res: any) => {
                this.results = JSON.parse(res.data);
                resolve(this.results);
            },
            (err: any) => {
            }
            )
        }
    })
  }

  getDeviceMobileNumber(id: any) {
    let url = this.UPIService + '/getsilentsmsmobile';
    let input_data = JSON.stringify({ "refId": id });
    return this.getHttpRequest(url, RequestMethod.Post, input_data);
  }
```

### homeComponent.ts

```
  this.commonServices.getDeviceMobileNumber(this.smsAuthText).then((data: any) => {
      console.log(data);
    }).catch((err: any) => {

    })
```

Comment: Elaborate why do you want to cancel the promise ?

Comment: I am working ionic hybrid application  and want to cancel all the API calls once app goes to the background. And I have onPause() event and inside that need to cancel all the API calls

Comment: Promises can not be canceled. However built in angular HttpClient returns observable on every method call. observables can be canceled. If that logic is really required you should upgrade your http service to support that

Comment: I would say switch to observables. You can add it to the this like `this.sub = this.service.getDeviceMobileNumber(this.smsAuthText).subscribe()` then when you finish you can call `this.sub.unsubscribe()` and the same can be done when you want to cancel the subscription.
Note that once the subscription is in progress you can't stop it same with a promise.
If you really want to block it somewhere you need to block it in the service with an if.
Might want to add a public function to set a boolean. `disableResolve(_boolean: boolean) { this.disableResolve = _boolean; }` `if(!disableResolve)`.